# Search functionality: loop through all database tables (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm looking for a way to loop through all my database tables in Laravel in order to add a search functionality to my website.

I guess there should be a way to do this without hardcoding all the table names.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$tables = DB::select("select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='your_database_name'");
```

Just change `your_database_name` to your own value. Then you can use the Laravel helper function, `array_pluck`, to get an array of the `table_name` values.

```
array_pluck($tables, 'table_name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to search in EVERY column without hardcoding every column name?